# Build Java project with tar one directory deeper in repository using Maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, maven, build, repository, maven-assembly-plugin

Running my Java Maven build as a Maven install, and using the Maven assembly plugin (maven-assembly-plugin), I can put some files from my unbuilt project into whatever format I like (dir, zip, tar) - a tar in my case. So when I run Maven install and look in my repository, I have the expected war file and the tar I created with the Maven-assembly-plugin.

so my built project has the following:

- repository/project.war
- repository/files.tar

How can I move my files.tar file one directory deeper so my structure is

- repository/project.war
- repository/anotherDirectory/files.tar?

**More Info**

Here's the plugin in my POM:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/repository.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
   [...]
</project>
```

And here's the repository.xml file:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>repository</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar</format>
  </formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory> 
   <fileSets>
         <fileSet>  
           <directory>${project.basedir}/files</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
             <filtered>true</filtered>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include> 
            </includes>           
        </fileSet>         
    </fileSets>  
</assembly>
```

(Would a possible solution be to have another assembly xml file that finds my assembled files.tar and puts that into a dir type? In what directory would I find my files.tar?)

Answer (score 1):

If "repository" means local repository or remote repository, then this cannot be done. The format of the local repository is fixed. The directories and file names are computed from the Maven coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version, classifier, extension).